# Alternative regex for complex match. Current one takes too long (space separated content but must match space included strings)

Tags: regex

We are building a parser of complex phone bills.  The problem is we have to match some strings which include spaces, so i'm keen to understand to optimise the following.

we need to match this string

```
             0499 799 099             First last                            The plan                                                          20 Nov 28 Nov                  $138.23
```

to extract the cell/mobile number and first last name and plan name "The plan".

the regex we have is

```
 / *([0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}) +(([a-zA-Z0-9\.\$\'\(\)]+ ?)+) +(([a-zA-Z0-9\.\$\'\(\)]+ ?)+) +([0-9][0-9] [A-Z][a-z][a-z]) ([0-9][0-9] [A-Z][a-z][a-z]) +\$([0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]) */
```

i know the " ?" forward matching etc. is costing us, but how else to do it if we need to match strings which include a single space.

welcome thoughts

thanks

Comment: `\s*` is any number of whitespaces. I'm not sure what you're working in but in most regex processors.

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: How is the regex supposed to know where the `First last` field ends and the next field (`The plan`) begins?  Is the name always exactly two words?  Is there always exactly one space between them?

Comment: this is in ruby. we are extracting the values matched between the ( ) pairs using regex.match(input line). the files are generated with lots of spaces to line up text, so we assume that the strings are based on a SINGLE space is allowed e.g. a 3 word name First Middle Last is allowed (single spaces separate). As with subsequent strings e.g. The plan could be "A Very long Plan name" because single spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex works as intended:

```
/^\s+([\d\s]{12})\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)[\s]{2,}/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cA8lY6/2)

---

Explanation:

```
^ assert position at start of the string
\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
1st Capturing group ([\d\s]{12})
    [\d\s]{12} match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: {12} Exactly 12 times
        \d match a digit [0-9]
        \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
2nd Capturing group (.*?)
    .*? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
3rd Capturing group (.*?)
    .*? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
4th Capturing group (.*?)
    .*? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
[\s]{2,} match a single character present in the list below
    Quantifier: {2,} Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
```

Explanation: